# Excel cell referencing

Tags: microsoft-excel

Starting cell: Either has text in it or is blank with no data at all.
Referencing Cell: the original text shows as referenced; however, when the starting cell is blank the referenced cell contains a 0.

Question: How do I get rid of the 0s without adding a blank space in the starting cell?

Comment: Could you perhaps include some reference or mockup data to help clarify your question?

Comment: Format the result as text `=TEXT()`

Comment: Starting cells on INPUT worksheet: A1: Approved   A2: no data at all                           OUTPUT worksheet: A1 properly reflects the cell reference and shows Approved however cell A2 shows a 0 instead of a blank cell

Comment: Figured it out. I just had to go through File>Options>Advanced>Display option for Worksheet and Uncheck "show a zero in cells that have zero value".

Comment: you can do : `=IF(OR(ISTEXT(A1),A1=""),"",A1)` in the target cell , right?

Answer (score 0):

**This Formula can help you to get rid from Zero.**

```
=IF(OR(A1<>"",B1<>""), A1+B1,TEXT(A1+B1,";"))
```

**How it works:**

- This Formula will Add, value in A1 with B1, when 
  either both or one has value. But return `Blank` 
  instead of `Zero` if both cells are blank.
- `;` can be used as cell Format also, if `Zero` 
  needs to replace with `Blank`.

Answer (score 0):

In your referencing cell, you can use something similar to:

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)`

So if you have a value entered into cell A1, it will display A1; if nothing is entered into A1, it will display "", or blank.